# Bluetooth Controller using Arduino Uno and HC-05 doesn't work when connected to PC

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I had an old Guitar Hero guitar that had the circuit board on the inside broken, so I decided to replace it with an Arduino Uno and an HC-05 to make it work over bluetooth. I installed the HID capable RN42 software onto the HC-05, then used the commands to set it to HID mode. Then I wired it according to this [schematic](https://github.com/theawsomeavr/arduino-bluetooth-gamepad/blob/master/Schematic_arduino-bl-gamepad_Sheet-1_20180527134715.png), but didn't wire any of the joysticks and only wired 5 pushbuttons out of the twelve in the sketch.

With this [sketch](https://github.com/theawsomeavr/arduino-bluetooth-gamepad/blob/master/arduino_bl_gamepad/arduino_bl_gamepad.ino) uploaded to the arduino, I connected it to a laptop, but when I open Joystick Properties on Windows, the buttons don't respond. I've looked for hours trying to find out if the code I used was faulty and making sure I wired the buttons correctly. Could the missing joysticks and buttons be causing this, or is there another aspect I should check?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out the general area of the problem. Figure out what actually works. As it stands, you could be facing one or ten problems anywhere from bad soldering, failure to flash the firmware, improper powering, missing Windows driver, etc. You are too early in the troubleshooting to get good suggestions here.

For your concrete question -- missing joysticks and buttons is probably not a problem here. You need to check *all* other aspects.